# TensorFlow graph with variable-iteration sections

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am creating a TensorFlow graph which has two portions: an encoder and a decoder; the decoder is followed by the optimization. Both the encoder and decoder are recurrent neural networks with enrollings dependent on variable-length input and target sequences, respectively. In other words, if the input sequence has 5 elements and the target sequence has 6 elements, the encoder must have 5 enrollings and the decoder must have 6 enrollings. I though I could accomplish this by creating two variables above the graph:

```
len_input = 1
len_target = 1
```

and in the graph have code:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
...
    # Encoder
    for t in range(len_input):
       ...

    # Decoder
    for t in range(len_target):
        ...
```

Then when I run a session, I'd update them accordingly:

```
with sess = tf.Session(graph=graph):
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
for step in range(num_batches):
    input = en_data.pop()
    len_input = input.shape[1]
    target = fr_data.pop()
    len_target = target.shape[1]
```

However, this is not at all producing the desired result. Instead, the graph only enrolls both the encoder and decoder once, as when the graph is first compiled.

Before you tell me that I can save Tensors across enrollings, the issue with that in my case is that the loss function is dependent on the output of the decoder, which is dependent on the output of the encoder. In other words, the optimizer optimizes all of the weights acting in both the encoder and decoder, meaning they all need to be in one graph. If I were to save values Tensors across enrollings, I'd need to create two separate graphs for encoder and decoder because the number of enrollings for the two need not be the same.

I am very stumped on this. At first, I thought to have a placeholder to which I'd feed the number of enrollings of the encoder and decoder, but the placeholder itself is a Tensor and hence can't be used in the `range` function in the for loop. I have no idea what I could do. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow supports dynamic unrolling of loops using control flow constructs in the graph. Instead of using a Python `for` loop to define the iteration, you can use one of the following interfaces, which let you define the body of your loop as a Python object or function:

- If your encoder and decoder match TensorFlow's [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#RNNCell) interface, you can use [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn) to define an RNN with a varying number of timesteps. The `sequence_length` argument allows you to specify the length of each sequence in the batch as a `tf.Tensor`, and TensorFlow will execute the cell the appropriate number of times.
- If instead the loop body can be represented more easily as a Python function, you can use the [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop) or [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#scan) higher-order functions to define the loop.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try out `tf.while_loop` and let you know how it goes, but that seems like the correct answer.